# Changed Compatibility Level From 100 to 130 - Why did performance regress?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

We are working on SQL Server 2016 and noticed that the master was on compatibility level 130 but one of our production databases was still on 2008 level 100 so we switched it and we are currently taking a performance hit on certain stored procs/functions. Our main function that once took 20 seconds is now taking over a minute. I updated the stats and cleared the query plan cache for that one object - should it be cleared for the entire database? Any other suggestions? We just did this like 30 minutes ago.

Comment: **[Cardinality estimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: Check the query plans for the two settings.  If they have changed, you can probably use a query hint to get the original performance.

Comment: I ended up turning on LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION and it brought it back to the 20 seconds but isn't this a bigger issue?